# script for win/dos to create folders from list of names in a file

Tags: windows, scripting, directory

Scripting question.   Dang, it should be easier than this.     I have a file with a list of names.   I'd like to turn those names into folders.   Whenever I try the FOR loop, all I get is the name of the file I want to read from being created as a folder, not the contents of the file being turned into folders.    Just want to mkdir for each item in the list.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to open the list of names in word and do copy and replace. Replace ^p with ^pmkdir this will replace all carraige returns (^p) with a carriage return and the mkdir command. Then save it as a bat and run it. There's def a cleaner way to do this if its going to be used over and over, but this is quick quick.

Comment: +1 - I like it. Quick, simple, easy, and it works.

Comment: I generally use Excel for generating batch files like this, but this method will work too.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
for /f %d in (listfiles) do md %d
```

This makes a directory under the current directory for each line in a file called "listfiles" in the current directory.

If you saved the file as a .txt file, make sure to reflect that in the command.

```
for /f %d in (listfiles.txt) do md %d
```

Answer (score 2):

The code `for /f %d in (listfile) do md %d` is nice but if you want to use it in a batch file you need to add extra % to the variable. `for /f %%d in (listfile) do md %%d`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming list of names are stored in a text file called dirlist.txt, then the command should be like this:

for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %i in (dirlist.txt) do md %i

Answer (score 2):

The other examples will read only up until it encounters a space or \newline (by default). Directories, of course, can have spaces. I just used this in batch to create 120+ directories (with spaces in names) using lines copied out of excel (items were already quoted).

If your folders/dirs have spaces in them, wrap quotes around each filename in the text file. (Of course if you need to do this, then you could just as easily search/replace and prepend 'md ' to each line.. and run that)

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=,"  %%d in (dirs.txt) do md %%d
```

Comment: A slightly more complicated example that creates & copies folders:      
https://gist.github.com/bmatthewshea/220f14fb0d421f1b1eaf5788d279e7be

Answer (score 1):

if you have powershell then
gc listfile | %{md $_}

Answer (score 0):

None of the other suggestions worked. I finally got it working in a bat file with:

```
% for /F %%d IN (yourfile.txt) DO md %%d
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `%%d` allows `md` to make directories with spaces.

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%d IN (folderlist.txt) DO md "%%d"
```